# AbstractJavaScriptComponent Client To Server function call

Tags: java, vaadin

I want to call a server side function from the client javascript. I am not so sure what I am doing wrong here:

```
public class Test extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent {

 public Test() {
    addFunction("notifyServer", new JavaScriptFunction() {

        @Override
        public void call(JsonArray arguments) {
            Notification.show("The client notified you!");

        }
    });
}
```

And from the Javascript connector.js I call it like this

```
function test(){
    this.notifyServer();
    notifyServer();
}
```

None of these above works. Everytime I get the same stacktrace

> Uncaught TypeError: this.notifyServer is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. I forgot that `this` for the wrapper is only available in the scope of the connection wrapper. So in order to call the function I had to do this:

```
var serverObject;

window.demo_test_Test = function() {

    serverObject = this;
}

function test(){
    serverObject.notifyServer();
}
```